# Excuting query: "LINQ to Entitites does not recognize method 'System.Object getItem(System.String)'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

First of all, I have these models:
[image]

I got this query in my controller and I want to put the query result into the view model:

```
var query = (from d in db.ObjectCategories
                    join a in db.MatchingObjects on d.Id equals a.ObjectCategoryId into grp3                        
                    join b in db.Unlocks
                        on d.Id equals b.ObjectCategoryId into grp1
                    from m in grp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join c in db.Members
                        on m.StudentId equals c.Id into grp2
                    from n in grp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where m.ObjectCategoryId == null
                    && n.Id == null
                    && n.Id == (int)Session["UserId"]
                    orderby d.Id
                    select new LockedCatListViewModel()
                    {
                        AnimalCategory = d.CategoryName,
                        AnimalCategoryId = d.Id,
                        Animals = d.MatchingObjects
                    }).AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(x=> new LockedCatListViewModel()
                    {
                        AnimalCategory = x.AnimalCategory,
                        AnimalCategoryId = x.AnimalCategoryId,
                        Animals = x.Animals
                    });
        return View(query.ToList());
```

The View Model:

```
public class LockedCatListViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Animal Category Name")]
    public string AnimalCategory { get; set; }
    public int AnimalCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MatchingObject> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

However, whenever I want loop the item inside the Model in view page, or just return this model to the view page, I got the following error:

[image]

I have tried many different methods, I wonder what should be done inside my LINQ query in order to get the result of my LINQ query?

Problem solved by assigning the Session into a variable, and put the variable inside the Linq.

I think I have an incorrect LINQ query for this part

```
 && n.Id == null
 && n.Id == (int)Session["UserId"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is a number of issues. Firstly the error is must likely due to the call to `Session` in your linq.

So to solve this move the session call outside of the linq statement and assign to a variable.

```
int userId = (int)Session["userId"];
```

You can then use the `userId` variable in place of the session call.

I think you will still find issue with your query after this because of these lines:

```
&& n.Id == null
&& n.Id == (int)Session["UserId"] //or userId when you change it
```

How can the `n.Id` be null and a value?

Comment: Hi, Ashley Medway thanks for your reply, it works like a charm.

Comment: No problem, you will find whenever you need to call a method it needs to be done outside of Linq and Session["foo"] is really a method call.